# wpf thread trouble updating ui

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

i am having trouble updating the ui, i can't for the life of me figure out why, since i have followed online examples. can any one point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub btnLogIn_Click()
    Dim u As String = tbxUser.Text
    Dim p As String = tbxPassword.Password

    Dim taskAuth = Tasks.Task(Of Boolean).Factory.StartNew(Function() auth_Login(u, p))
    taskAuth.Wait()
    Dim is_user As Boolean = taskAuth.Result

    If is_user = False Then
        Dim shake As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("Shake"), Storyboard)
        shake.Begin()
        tbxUser.Focus()
    ElseIf is_user = True Then
        If chbxRemember.IsChecked Then
            My.Settings.name_User = u
            My.Settings.Save()
        Else
            My.Settings.name_User = String.Empty
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

        Dim myFrame As Frame = myWindow.MainFrame
        myFrame.Navigate(New mainMenu())
    End If

End Sub

Function auth_Login(u As String, p As String)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myWindow.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() progBar.IsIndeterminate = True)

    Dim is_user As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim login As New COGENT_Model.Security_Model
        is_user = login.check_user(u, p)
    Catch
        '99% db connection error
        Dim myFrame As Frame = myWindow.MainFrame
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myFrame.Navigate(New mainConexion()))
    End Try
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myWindow.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() progBar.IsIndeterminate = False)
    Return is_user
End Function
```

the main problem is in the function, since i want to know if the user exists. while this is being checked, i want a progress bar to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread on `taskAuth.Wait()`.

Instead you should refactor your code this way:

```
Private Sub btnLogIn_Click()
    Dim u As String = tbxUser.Text
    Dim p As String = tbxPassword.Password

    Dim taskAuth = Tasks.Task(Of Boolean).Factory.StartNew(Function() auth_Login(u, p))
End Sub

Function auth_Login(u As String, p As String)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myWindow.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() progBar.IsIndeterminate = True)

    Dim is_user As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim login As New COGENT_Model.Security_Model
        is_user = login.check_user(u, p)
    Catch
        '99% db connection error
        Dim myFrame As Frame = myWindow.MainFrame
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myFrame.Navigate(New mainConexion()))
    End Try
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() myWindow.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() progBar.IsIndeterminate = False)

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
        If is_user = False Then
            Dim shake As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("Shake"), Storyboard)
            shake.Begin()
            tbxUser.Focus()
        ElseIf is_user = True Then
            If chbxRemember.IsChecked Then
                My.Settings.name_User = u
                My.Settings.Save()
            Else
                My.Settings.name_User = String.Empty
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If

            Dim myFrame As Frame = myWindow.MainFrame
            myFrame.Navigate(New mainMenu())
        End If
    End Sub)
    Return is_user
End Function
```

Neither compiled nor tested but you get the idea...

Comment: that was it! i had the Wait() in there to wait for thread to check existance of a user.